# How to extract all the nested keys using Pyspark from JSON

Tags: pyspark

I can only use pyspark.sql, not other libs like pandas or pyspark.pandas. I have a JSON file like this and want to extract all the nks to a column, which are nk1 and nk2 in this example.

```
{
    "key":
    {
        "nk1":
        {
            "nnk1": 0,
            "nnk2": 0,
            "nnk3": 0,
            "nnk4": 8888
        },
        "nk2":
        {
            "nnk1": 0,
            "nnk2": 0,
            "nnk3": 0,
            "nnk4": 8888
        }
        }
}
```

Expected Results:

| Column |
| --- |
| nk1 |
| nk2 |

However, when I read spark JSON file, all the key and nks are StructType which I can not explode. Here are my codes:

```
raw = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("file/path")
>>> raw.printSchema()
root
 |-- key: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nk1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nnk1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nnk2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nnk3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nnk4: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nk2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nnk1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nnk2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nnk3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- nnk4: long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get nk columns like that;

```
set(raw.collect()[0]["key"].asDict().keys())
```